# Is there a way to sort values in a CSV file in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, csv, sorting

I have a csv file that outputs rows like this:

```
Distributed Systems|SOFE 4790U|M|14|10|17|0|University Building A1 UA2240
Research Methods|SSCI 2900U|F|14|10|17|0|61 Charles DTA219
Social Control|SSCI 2030U|R|14|10|17|0|61 Charles DTA219
```

Is there anyway to sort the values in the csv file based on one column? Like say The 3rd column which represents day of the week. How would I go about sorting it by M T W R F in that order? I have been trying to use case classes and overriding the equals/compare method but not sure where to go from what I have?

```
case class Foo(i: String)
{
    override def equals()
}
val a = Foo("F")
val b = Foo("M")
println(a<b)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm unable to re-create the posted error but I see that you're getting a MatchError which very likely means that you're encountering a `Char` value other than the expected M,T,W,R,F. Also, I notice that you aren't saving the `sortBy()` results so the final `println()` output won't be in sorted order.

Comment: I've found the error I added an S case to my sortBy function and it works now.. Please see my updated code.. Also I want the list to keep its MTWRF sorted order but I also want to sort each day based on starting hour and starting minute.. When I try using var lol1 = lol.sortBy(_.startHr)
 var lol2 = lol1.sortBy(_.startMin) it forgets the MTWRF order and just sorts by starting hour.. Is there anyway to keep both? Thanks for the response

Comment: There are a few ways to do it. All of which require more space than SO comments allow. Search SO for: `[scala] sort multiple`

Comment: Thanks I got it to work using the updated code. Thanks for that. Also lastly is there anyway for it to output without the "Record" in Record(Physics I,PHY 1010U,R,14,10,15,30,Library Portables UL4) I just w ant it to print Physics I,PHY 1010U,R,14,10,15,30,Library Portables UL4

Comment: Override the `toString()` method of the `Record()` case class. Then the `println()` output is whatever format you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement it as string comparison but it would be cleaner to build separate AST of `DayOfWeek` type.

```
sealed trait DayOfWeek extends Comparable[DayOfWeek] {
  val value: Int
  override def compareTo(o: DayOfWeek): Int = value compareTo o.value
}

object DayOfWeek {
  case object M extends DayOfWeek { val value = 0 }
  case object T extends DayOfWeek { val value = 1 }
  case object W extends DayOfWeek { val value = 2 }
  case object R extends DayOfWeek { val value = 3 }
  case object F extends DayOfWeek { val value = 4 }
}
```

Now, we won't see `<` operator but, fortunately, Scala has concept of extension methods.

```
object DayOfWeek {
  // ...

  implicit class syntax(dow: DayOfWeek) {
    def <(other: DayOfWeek): Boolean = (dow compareTo other) < 0
  }
}
```

Now you could use it like this

```
import DayOfWeek._
println(M < T)
// true
```

and if you wanted to construct this type out of string you might go for something like

```
object DayOfWeek {
  // ...

  // this method is unsafe, you might consider returning option instead, this is just for demonstartion purposes
  def apply(s: String): DayOfWeek = s match {
    case "M" => M
    case "T" => T
    case "W" => W
    case "R" => R
    case "F" => F
  }
}

import DayOfWeek._
println(DayOfWeek("M") < DayOfWeek("T"))
// true
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried implementing what you said through a case class but I'm getting an error. The error and my updated code is edited above.